# change radio button check status using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons with one input text, when I insert value more than 12 it will automatically check `RadioBtn2` otherwise it will check `RadioBtn1`

It works OK but when I return to textbox and change the value again it not working until I refresh the page

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field222').change(function() {
    var text_value = $("#field222").val();
    if (text_value >= '12') {
      $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn2"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
      $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn1"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='input-lg' id='field222'>
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn1' value='option1' checked>First
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn2' value='option1' >Secend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the value and if condition like this

For versions of jQuery equal or above (>=) 1.6, use:

```
var text_value = parseInt($("#field222").val());
if (text_value >= 12) {
  $('#RadioBtn1').prop("checked", true);
} else {
  $('#RadioBtn2').prop("checked", true);
}
```

Comment: its solve the problem, I must use `prop` instead of `$('input:radio[id="RadioBtn1"]').prop("checked", true);` thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have incorrect condition in if statemenet. You need to parse the value to integer before making greater than check.

You also need to change change event to keyup and set property checked as true:

```
var text_value = parseInt($("#field222").val());
if (text_value >= 12) {
  $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn1"]').prop("checked", true);
} else {
  $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn2"]').prop("checked", true);
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field222').keyup(function() {
    var text_value = parseInt($("#field222").val());
     debugger;
     if (text_value >= 12) {
       $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn1"]').prop("checked", true);
     } else {
       $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn2"]').prop("checked", true);
     }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='input-lg' id='field222'>
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn1' value='option1' checked>First
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn2' value='option1' checked>Secend
```

Comment: its still the same (working for one time until i refresh the page)

Comment: In which case, check the console for errors elsewhere in your JS as this works absolutely fine, and is the best approach: http://jsfiddle.net/fr5cgwuh/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this answer was changed to use `.prop` after OPs comment that it didn't work (as it still used `.attr`).

Answer (score 1):

Try the code with keypress function and prop for radio button check.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field222').keyup(function() {
    var text_value = parseInt($("#field222").val());

    if (text_value >=12) {

      $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn1"]').prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn2"]').prop("checked", true);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='integer' class='input-lg' id='field222'>
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn1' value='option1' checked>First
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn2' value='option1' checked>Secend
 Run code
```

Comment: Not sure about the `.length` change, but `.prop` was the fix required.

Comment: Updated code ,Use keyup function and parseInt for numeric validation

Answer (score 0):

> when I return to textbox and change the value again it not working

this is because you are using `.attr` when you should be using `.prop`.  Essentially, the 2nd radio's .attr is always set and because you can only have one checked, the browser shows the second as checked.

It works fine if you use `.prop` *or* if you use `.removeAttr` before setting it again.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field222').change(function() {
    var text_value = $("#field222").val();
    if (text_value >= '12') {    
      $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn2"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
      $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn1"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='input-lg' id='field222'>
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn1' value='option1' checked>First
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn2' value='option2' >Secend
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field222').change(function() {
    var text_value = $("#field222").val();
    $('input:radio').removeAttr("checked");
    if (text_value >= '12') {    
      $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn2"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
      $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn1"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='input-lg' id='field222'>
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn1' value='option1' checked>First
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn2' value='option2' >Secend
```

---

You will also need to parse the value to an int if you want to check it numerically, but it works with strings as-is (use "0" and "12" to show it working).

Comment: thanks for help, that's right I should use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#field222').keyup(function() {
    var text_value = $("#field222").val();
    if (text_value >= 12) {
      $('#RadioBtn2').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#RadioBtn1').prop('checked', true); 
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='input-lg' id='field222'>
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn1' value='option1' checked>First
<input type='radio' name='Radios' id='RadioBtn2' value='option1' >Secend
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen one issue in above example that you are taking integer value and trying to compare with string.

Instead of

```
 if (text_value >= '12') {    
  $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn2"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
} else {
  $('input:radio[id="RadioBtn1"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Use

```
if (text_value >= 12) {
$("input[id='RadioBtn1']").prop("checked", true);

} else {
$("input[id='RadioBtn2']").prop("checked", true);
```

[See Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/HuZcM/1137/
)